# Understanding oauth2 and JWT with Azure

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-api-management

I have an Azure API Management instance. It serves as proxy for a public on-prem backend.
I have setup oauth2 using Azure AD and Azure APIM (grant_type client_credentials). So after a POST call to `/token` it will receive a JWT token.

This JWT token can be used to perform a `GET` request to my APIM. Only valid tokens are accepted. So that part seems to work. The `GET` call is routed to my on-prem public backend.

But how should I secure my on-prem backend? People can just call it directly without going through Azure. We can't just whitelist the APIM IP. Is it a good idea to pass the JWT token from APIM to that backend and check it there again (what info do I need for that?).

Comment: What's the point of APIM in this case if you don't want to lock the backend down just to APIM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These days many organizations follow a zero trust approach. This means every API runs JWT validation on every request, as in [this API of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.azure/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authenticator.ts#L31). This also enables the API to run claims based authorization before allowing access to resources.

This protects against both internal and external threats and feels like a good fit for your use case. The code required is also quite straightforward. Therefore configure APIM to forward the JWT access token to the API.